# Java - directly reading a file without downloading and storing locally

Tags: java

I want to directly read a file, put it into a string without storing the file locally. I used to do this with an old project, but I don't have the source code anymore. I used to be able to get the source of my website this way.

However, I don't remember if I did it by "InputStream to String array of lines to String", or if I directly read it into a String.

Was there a function for this, or am I remembering wrong?

(Note: this function would be the PHP equivalent of `file_get_contents($path)`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `InputStreamReader` to convert from a binary input stream to a `Reader` which is appropriate for reading text.

After that, you need to read to the end of the reader.

Personally I'd do all this with [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which has convenience methods for this sort of thing, e.g. [`CharStreams.toString(Readable)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#toString%28java.lang.Readable%29).

When you create the `InputStreamReader`, make sure you supply the appropriate character encoding - if you don't, you'll get junk text out (just like trying to play an MP3 file as if it were a WAV, for example).

Comment: Minor: to get a Reader for a file, you can go straight to FileReader without explicitly creating an InputStream or an InputStreamReader.

Comment: @Vance: Avoid FileReader like the plague - it doesn't allow you to specify the encoding to use :(

Answer (score 3):

Check out [apache-commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and for your use case [FileUtils.readFileToString(File file)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)
 (should not be to hard to get a File form the path).

You can use the library or have a look at the code - as this is open.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to read a `File` into a `String`.

But there is a quick alternative - read the `File` into a Byte array and convert it into a String.

Untested:

```
File f = new File("/foo/bar");
InputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(f);
ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(int data = fStream.read(); data > -1; data = fStream.read()) {
  b.write(data);
}
String theResult = new String(bStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```